Photo-excited Radiation/Electric Current with Green Function Method
Suppose there is an incident photo with a specific frequency hitting the material; the incident photo is absorbed by this material. Meanwhile, the material is excited by this incident photo and generates another radiation electromagnetic wave with another specific frequency or generates an electric current.
Is there any way to describe this phenomenon, such as a formula with the green function method?
Is there any reference, discussing this kind of photo-excited radiation/electric current?
Would anyone please give me some hint/clue on how to deduct this materials response, which could be an electric-current or an electromagnetic wave, to the photoexcitation?
Thank you in advance.

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this question on Matter Modeling SE.

@Tobias Thank you for your suggestion. I will switch to matter modeling section.
